# When can the fiscal multiplier be negative?

Tags: macroeconomics, reference-request, economic-growth

I am looking for a case study or data which shows a negative (fiscal/spending) multiplier effect.

Does anyone know a study where this is analyzed?

Comment: I added the information you gave as a comment to BKay's answer, I hope this is in your interest. Unfortunately, it makes BKay's answer obsolete, but maybe helps to reopen the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The paper [How Big (Small?) are Fiscal Multipliers?](http://www.nber.org/papers/w16479) by Ethan Ilzetzki, Enrique G. Mendoza, Carlos A. Végh (2010)should give you useful information.

> We contribute to the debate on the macroeconomic effects of fiscal
>   stimuli by showing that the impact of government expenditure shocks
>   depends crucially on key country characteristics, such as the level of
>   development, exchange rate regime, openness to trade, and public
>   indebtedness. Based on a novel quarterly dataset of government
>   expenditure in 44 countries, we find that (i) the output effect of an
>   increase in government consumption is larger in industrial than in
>   developing countries, (ii) the fiscal multiplier is relatively large
>   in economies operating under predetermined exchange rates but is zero
>   in economies operating under flexible exchange rates; (iii) fiscal
>   multipliers in open economies are smaller than in closed economies;
>   (iv) fiscal multipliers in high-debt countries are negative.

Answer (score 5):

The fiscal multiplier is [the ratio of a change in national income to the change in government spending that causes it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiscal_multiplier#Examples).

Assume that the government runs a balanced budget and so any raise in spending comes with a raise in taxes. Imagine there are three types of people in this economy, Friday has a low marginal propensity ($\alpha\in(0,1)$) to consume (MPC) and Robinson Crusoe has a high ($\beta\in(0,1)$) MPC, and a massive number of other people with an MPC of $\gamma\in(0,1)$ such that the economy wide MPC can be thought of $\gamma$. Assume Crusoe's labor supply does not respond to taxes.

If you tax Crusoe \$1 and spend that \$1 on Friday then Crusoe cuts his consumption by $\beta$ dollars and Friday increases his by alpha dollars. Therefore, the the change in consumption, is:$$\alpha - \beta$$ which is negative by construction. In representative agent models the relationship between the multiplier and the MPC is:
$$Multiplier = 1 / (1 - MPC) $$

Here is a summary from the Investopedia how this works:

> Suppose a large corporation decides to build a factory in a small town
> and that spending on the factory for the first year is \$5 million.
> That \$5 million will go to electricians, engineers and other various
> people building the factory. If MPC is equal to 0.8, those people will
> spend \$4 million on various goods and services. The various business
> and individual receiving that \$4 million will in turn spend \$3.2
> million and so on.
>
> If the marginal propensity to consume is equal to 0.8 (4 / 5), then
> the multiplier can be calculated as:
>
> Multiplier = 1 / (1 - MPC) = 1 / (1 - 0.8) = 1 / 0.2 = 5

But in our example, there really are two shocks, one negative to Crusoe and one positive to Friday. The total effect is:
$$\frac{\alpha}{1-\gamma} - \frac{\beta}{1-\gamma} =  \frac{\alpha - \beta}{1-\gamma} <0$$
because the consumption reduction of Crusoe and the consumption increase of Friday both propagate into the same population with MPC of $\gamma$. So the multiplier if this policy would be negative.

It is also possible to get a negative multiplier from a deadweight loss of taxation.

Comment: Thank you for the deep explanation! I understand the theory more clearly, but I am looking for a real-world example, such as a case study on the negative (fiscal/spending) multiplier effect. Do you know any material like this, BKay?

Answer (score -3):

Only the injection is multiplied not the withdrawal - once money leaves the economy that is the end of it's journey in the circular flow of income - full stop.

The injection continues being spent around the economy which is why it is subject to the Multiplier.

There is no negative Multiplier.

The Multiplier is not a micro concept - the withdrawal is on the money supply not on an individual or even groups income even if he is called Clouseau.

Therefore there is no real world example - only in the surreal world of micro economists.